# Chaining doesn't work in lodash and jsfiddle

Tags: javascript

I am trying to run this example on jsfiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/3wsny0r2/

However i am not getting any output any ideas ?

```
var characters = [
  { 'name': 'barney',  'age': 36 },
  { 'name': 'fred',    'age': 40 },
  { 'name': 'pebbles', 'age': 1 }
];

 var youngest = _.chain(characters)
    .sortBy('age')
    .map(function(chr) { return chr.name + ' is ' + chr.age; })
    .first()
    .value()

console.log(youngest)
```

Comment: `first()` already returns a value.

Comment: elclanrs thanks it works after removing the value from the method chaining.Please post it as a answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`first()` already returns a value, the first item of the array after sorting and mapping. Remove `.value()` and it will work.